# Java Compiler gives a strange Error

Tags: java

I’m working on a Java project and I can compile my project inside eclipse (with JDK 1.6.0_14) without any issue. But when I’m compiling the project inside my build system I’m getting following strange error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: javax/xml/marshal/StreamScanner, method: fail signature: (ILjava/la
g/String;)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
at javax.xml.marshal.XMLScanner.open(XMLScanner.java:138)
```

Any Idea?

Thanks
Upul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's another JAR in your CLASSPATH that contains a version of `javax.xml.marshal.StreamScanner` that conflicts with the one built into the JDK.